# Wordpress Admin Panel Show Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wlwmanifest_link() (previously declared in

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error, redeclare

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wlwmanifest_link() (previously declared in /home/freefire/public_html/wp-includes/general-template.php:3382) in /home/freefire/public_html/wp-includes/deprecated.php on line 4635

How Can i Solve this.  Please Help me

[Hare is the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBK0t.png)

I change the name of Plugin Folder And Theme Folder But Doesn't Work.  Cause the problem in wp-includes Folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There could multiple reasons.

Maybe you have conflicting on your plugins

- backup from your site
- deactive all the plugins with rename plugins folders
- activate plugins one by one until the error is reproduced

Maybe you have conflicting code in your functions.php file.
Replace default functions.php codes to your functions.php

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error after a failed update of WordPress 5 to WordPress 6.3. The update failed because the server was running on PHP 7 and WordPress 6 requires PHP 8. The WordPress installation ended up in an inconsistent state containen files from both versions 5 and 6. I solved the issue by downloading zip file from WordPress.com and updating by FTP: overwriting all the files except wp_config.php (and wp_content)